# C: declare a constant pointer to an array of constant characters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, constants

I am trying to understand array declarations, constness, and their resulting variable types.

The following is allowed (by my compiler):

```
      char s01[] = "abc" ;  // typeof(s01) = char*
const char s02[] = "abc" ;  // typeof(s02) = const char* (== char const*)
char const s03[] = "abc" ;  // typeof(s03) = char const* (== const char*)
```

Alternatively, we can declare the array size manually:

```
      char s04[4] = "abc" ;  // typeof(s04) = char*
const char s05[4] = "abc" ;  // typeof(s05) = const char* (== char const*)
char const s06[4] = "abc" ;  // typeof(s06) = char const* (== const char*)
```

How do I get a resulting variable of type `const char* const`?  The following are not allowed (by my compiler):

```
const char s07 const[] = "abc" ;
char const s08 const[] = "abc" ;
const char s09[] const = "abc" ;
char const s10[] const = "abc" ;
const char s11 const[4] = "abc" ;
char const s12 const[4] = "abc" ;
const char s13[4] const = "abc" ;
char const s14[4] const = "abc" ;
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not wholly sure that C supports the const ptr* const thing that C++ does.

Comment: The following is a very useful tool: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=declare+bar+as+constant+pointer+to+array+of+constant+char ; http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=declare+bar+as+constant+pointer+to+constant+char

Comment: [I asked this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7260045/192993): `const char a[const]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const char *const s15 = "abc";
```

Comment: It is helpful to read from right-to-left to understand what is constant. E.g. `char *const s15` means constant-pointer-to-char. `char const *s15` means pointer-to-constant-char. `char const *const s15` means constant-pointer-to-constant-char. Try it! Right-to-left!

Comment: @PP: The right-to-left rule doesn't apply in all circumstances, though.  e.g. `int blah[5][2]`.  The best summary of how to read declarators I've ever found is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x82y1z4.aspx.

Comment: @PP: It's not right-to-left any more than it's left-to-right, it's **inside-out**.

Comment: This is the answer I was seeking.  I was stuck on the idea that [] allocates on the stack (when declared in a function).  If it is a constant pointer to an array of constant chars, I don't need to allocate on the stack.  One time in program data space is OK.  Who knows where "abc" is allocated here, and who cares.  We use `s15` as an absolute constant.  We cannot reassign the pointer `s15` nor can we change the value(s) to which it points (`"abc"`).

Thanks!

Comment: C declarations should be read in a clockwise spiral: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 6):

Your first `typeof` comments aren't really correct.  The type of `s01` is `char [4]`, and the types of `s02` and `s03` are `const char [4]`.  When used in an expression and not the subject of either the `&` or `sizeof` operators, they will evaluate to rvalues of type `char *` and `const char *` respectively, pointing at the first element of the array.

You can't declare them in such a way that they decay to an rvalue that itself is const-qualified; it doesn't really make any sense to have a const-qualified rvalue, since rvalues can't be assigned to.  It's like saying you want a `5` constant that is of type `const int` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 5):

`s01` et al are not really pointer types, they're array types.  In that sense, they already act a bit like `const` pointers (you cannot re-assign `s01` to point somewhere else, for instance).

Answer (score 3):

Use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org):

```
cdecl> declare foo as constant pointer to array of constant char
Warning: Unsupported in C -- 'Pointer to array of unspecified dimension'
        (maybe you mean "pointer to object")
const char (* const foo)[]
cdecl> declare foo as constant pointer to array 4 of constant char
const char (* const foo)[3]
cdecl> declare foo as constant pointer to constant char
const char * const foo
```

Pointers to arrays are rarely used in C; usually API functions expect a pointer to the first element.